# Why could not my Blazor project consume MyProj.HttpApi.Client correctly?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor, abp

I used **ABP CLI** generated a MVC template, with which I would like to try a **Blazor Server** project. I do add a MyProjBlazorModule which was as same as every common Module, just like the **ConsoleTestApp project** did:

```
namespace MyProj.Blazor
{
    [DependsOn(
        typeof(MyProjHttpApiClientModule),
        typeof(AbpHttpClientIdentityModelModule)
        )]
    public class MyProjBlazorModule : AbpModule
    {
    }
}
```

Then I added the module as service to **ConfigureServices**  method:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSyncfusionBlazor();
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
        services.AddApplication<TaurusBlazorModule>();

    }
```

for a rapid test, I also copied **ClientDemoService** class from template project **MyProj.HttpApi.Client.ConsoleTestApp** , and I consume it in my index.razor like this:

```
@inject ClientDemoService _clientService
...
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{

    await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    profile = await _clientService.RunAsync();
}
```

But it couldn't work, with a error message in browser:

> *InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultAuthenticateScheme found. The default schemes can
>   be set using either AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme) or
>   AddAuthentication(Action configureOptions).*

while If I copy code identical to the console test project like this:

```
        using (var application = AbpApplicationFactory.Create<MyProjConsoleApiClientModule>())
        {
            application.Initialize();

            var demo = application.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ClientDemoService>();
            profile = AsyncHelper.RunSync(() => demo.RunAsync());

        }
```

and it worked. I would like to know the difference between using ABP module and explicitly calling an ugly ServiceProvider method here, and how can I fix this issue in some correct and beautiful way?

Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: This error means you did setup authentication : `services.AddAuthentication`

Comment: Yes I have tried that, like: services.AddAuthentication(o => { o.DefaultScheme = "TokenAuthenticationScheme"; }); But the issue was the same...

Comment: But it's not enought, you need to setup an authentication handler too, (cookie, jwt, oidc, etc..) and setup the authentication middleware in your pipe `app.UseAuthentication()` : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: I will study it. Thank you, but why the console demo dose not need such configure and works well? Is "application.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ClientDemoService>();" did any magical thing than from a module registration?

Comment: Because it setup the authentication for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I have got what's wrong with that. In the template source code from **abp CLI**, the **MyProjHttpApiHostModule's ConfigureAuthentication** method register authenticate service like this:

```
    private void ConfigureAuthentication(ServiceConfigurationContext context, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        context.Services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = configuration["AuthServer:Authority"];
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.ApiName = "MyProj";
                options.JwtBackChannelHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
                {
                    ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator
                };
            });
    }
```

where AddAuthentication() method used **empty parameter** overload, that caused the *No authenticationScheme was specified* error. I referenced [IdentityServer4 official document](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/apis.html) and found the right way to do:

```
context.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                ...
            });
```

That's easy, I should set the default scheme **JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme** 
using a different overload of AddAuthentication method just as the error had reported.

I hope this post could help someone facing the same or similar issue.